# Passing an array through "isalpha" through a loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I've been at this for quite some time now and the existing answers offer little to no help. I am new to programming and am trying to write a sub-part of my program which tries to check whether any given input is constituted solely of alphabets.

For this, the idea I have in mind is to pass an entire array through the isalpha function by using a loop which passes each character at a time. The idea makes logical sense but I am having syntactic trouble implementing it. I will greatly appreciate any help!

Below is my code-

```
printf("Please type the message which needs to be encrypted: ");
string p = GetString();

for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
{
   if(isalpha(**<what I'm putting here is creating the problem, I think>**) = true)
   {
      printf("%c", p[i]);
   }

}
```

Comment: string in C? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709323/does-c-have-a-string-type

Comment: Hmm... 'isalpha() = true' ? That shouldn't even compile...

Comment: @Quentin, that's what I answered, nice thing I am not the only one who saw that!

Comment: @G.Samaras On a side note, '== true' is always redundant, and can lead to subtle bugs so I'd simply drop it. Note that the thing indeed won't compile since functions return rvalues.

Comment: @Quentin I agree! Updated my answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should modify your code as this (assuming you have the string type defined yourself):

```
printf("Please type the message which needs to be encrypted: ");
string p = GetString();

for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p); i < n; i++)
{
   if(isalpha(p[i]) == true) // HERE IS THE ERROR, YOU HAD =, NOT ==
   {
      printf("%c", p[i]);
   }

}
```

Operator `=` is for assignment and operator `==` is for comparison!

So what was happening? The assignment resulted in true, no matter what `p[i]` was.

As Quentin mentioned:

`if(isalpha(p[i]) == true)`

could be more elegant and error prune if written like this:

`if(isalpha(p[i]))`

Here is an example in C:

```
/* isalpha example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i = 0;
  char str[] = "C++";
  while (str[i]) // strings in C are ended with a null terminator. When we meet
  // the null terminator, while's condition will get false.
  {
    if (isalpha(str[i])) // check every character of str
       printf ("character %c is alphabetic\n",str[i]);
    else
       printf ("character %c is not alphabetic\n",str[i]);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/)

[Ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) of `isalpha()`.

[C does not have a string type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709323/does-c-have-a-string-type).

Tip: Next time post your code as it is!

Aslo, as Alter noticed, it would be nice to use:

`isalpha((unsigned char)str[i])`

and in your code

`isalpha((unsigned char)p[i])`

for [safety reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975913/does-ctype-h-still-require-unsigned-char).

Comment: A cast `isalpha((unsigned char)str[i])` [is needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975913/does-ctype-h-still-require-unsigned-char)

Comment: @G.Samaras- Thank you so much for explaining everything so well! I am teaching myself and often encounter roadblocks but its people like you who keep me going! Cheers :)

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? I can't upvote as I need 15 reputation. Additionally, I had another quick question- I tried to modify my code according to the suggestions but its throwing an "implicit declaration of function 'isalpha' error. Is there any way I can amend this? I also don't understand why is this error popping up :/

Comment: #include <ctype.h> is the solution, as mentioned in my 2nd example.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/).

I.e. parameter of isalpha() is i-th character of string p. The only question is how to access to i-th character. Usually you can use []. I.e. just use following code: `isalpha(p[i])` (I see that you already use [] in call of printf).

Also `isalpha(p[i]) = true` is wrong condition. It looks like you planned to check `isalpha(p[i]) == true` (you can skip `== true`).

Comment: The problem of the OP is not there!

Comment: You are welcome. I believe you would notice that too, if the OP would have posted his/her code as is. Hopefully, (s)he will follow my tip in the future. I think the +2 you have are fair.

Answer (score 0):

Late but:

both other answers say **omitting `== true`** is desirable, but don't say it **is necessary for portability**.

The C core-language operators `== != < <= > >= && ||` which return a 'logical' value use an `int` value of 1 for true and 0 for false. In C99 and up with `stdbool.h` and by common convention before that `true` is 1 and `false` is 0, so e.g. `if( (a < b) == true )` will work correctly, although it is redundant and many (including me) consider it poor style. Language elements that *test* a logical value, namely `if(c) while(c) for(;c;)` and the operands to `&& ||` and the left operand to `?:` consider any value that compares equal to 0 to be false, and any other value to be true.

The character-classification routines in `ctype.h` as well as some other **standard-library routines** like `feof(f)` and `ferror(f)` are specified to return *some nonzero int* for true and 0 (an int) for false, and on many implementations the nonzero **value used for true is not (always) 1**. In those cases `isalpha(whatever) == true` might result in testing say 4 == 1 and fail even when `whatever` is an alphabetic character. OTOH `isalpha(...) != false` or `isalpha(...) != 0` does work correctly if you really want to write something explicit.