# return array from subroutine in c program

Tags: c, arrays, string, subroutine

I have a program with a subroutine that processes numbers that are input into the subroutine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float test_subroutine(float x,float y)
{
    float a=105.252342562324;
    float b=108.252234256262;
    float d;
    float e;
    char var;

    d=x*a;
    e=y*b;

    sprintf(var,"%0.2f %0.2f",d,e);

    return var;
 }



 int main()
 {
      float variable[2];
      variable=test_subroutine(2.5,3.5);

 }
```

Now with this program the idea is I have either a string or variable like this:

```
368.386 270.63
```

Whether this is a string or array I want to be able to split this into two individual floating point numbers 368.386 and 270.63.  How do I tweak this program to accomplish this?

Comment: First make yopur program compile: A `char` is not a `float` , and you cannot write a string into a `char`.

Comment: Create a structure with that array inside. You can then normally return it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [strtok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889992/how-does-strtok-split-the-string-into-tokens-in-c). Then malloc an array of what you want and fill it up.

Answer (score 0):

The title you mentioned and the code you have shown doesn't seem to make sense as they dont match. If returning an array from a function is your concern, then please refer this

[How to return a local array from a C/C++ function?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/return-local-array-c-function/)

The code you have written returns a char but the return type of the function is float and hence this itself will raise an error when you compile.

As of the question that you asked at the last, of converting "368.386 270.63" to two individual floating point numbers, in C we dont have a native data type called String, by convention the language uses array of chars(refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709323/does-c-have-a-string-type) for more details on this),
Now for splitting a character array,you can use the [strtok()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strtok-strtok_r-functions-c-examples/) function.
To convert the character array to floating point numbers, use the [atof()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/) function.This returns a double, since you want float to be returned, explicitly convert it into float.