# Reading command-line argument in C and checking is it a digit

Tags: arrays, c, command-line-arguments, cs50

**Details about my goal**

In C, my program is supposed to take an input from command line, read it, make sure that it is a digit and then print out "Success" if true, "Usage: ./caesar key" if false.

**Expected results**

```
./caesar 33
Success
```

or

```
./caesar zzz
Usage: ./caesar key
```

**Actual results**

```
./caesar 33
Segmentation error
```

**What I've tried**

```
 int main (int argc, string argv[])
 {
   if (argc == 2)
   {
      if (isdigit(argv[1]))
      {
        printf("Success\n");
        return 0;
      }
```

or

```
if (argc == 2)
{
  if (isdigit(argv[0][1]))
  {
    printf("Success\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

or

```
int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
   if (argc == 2 && isdigit(argv[1]))
   {
     printf("Success\n");
     return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need to use the `isdigit` function, then you can use the [strspn](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strspn.htm) function as suggested by @Param Siddharth. However, **they are several corner-cases** with using

```
if (strspn(string, "-+0123456789") == strlen(string))
```

for instance that the values like `"-----"` would be **considered as a valid number**.

If you want to use the `isdigit` function than you need to go through all the `char`s in the *String* (instead of passing the entire *String* in one go) and check if each one of them is indeed a digit:

```
    ...
    int i, is_number = 1;
    for (i = 0; is_number && argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++){
        if(i == 0 && (argv[1][i] == '-' || argv[1][i] == '+')){
           continue;
        }   
        is_number = isdigit(string[i]);
     }
     // It should fail for Strings that are : empty, only "-" or "+"
    if(i == 0 || (i == 1 && !isdigit(argv[1][0])) || !is_number){
        printf("The String is not a Number \n");
        return 1;
     }
     printf("Success\n");
     return 0;
}
```

I tested with the inputs:

- "-", not a number
- "",  not a number
- "-1", number
- "+1", number
- "+1+1" not a number

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing wrong here is that you want to check if the entire string consists of digits, but you are passing the string itself to `isdigit`, which expects a `char`. What you can do is manually iterate through the `char` array and check if each `char` is a digit, or you can use the `strspn` function as demonstrated below.

```
strspn(argv[1], "0123456789") == strlen(argv[1])
```

This will compare the span of digits in the argument and return true if it is the same as the length of the string itself. If you want to allow + and - signs in the argument, use `"-+0123456789"` inside `strspn`, though that would result in a false positive for cases like `+++++` (as mentioned by @dreamcrash below), which is why defining a custom function is always a better option. Both the `strspn` and `strlen` functions are available in the `string.h` header.

Comment: I really like your answer, clean and simple. However, the only problem is that values like "-----" would be considered as a valid number.

Comment: @dreamcrash I agree! Such cases would fail. I will edit my answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int main (int argc, string argv[])
> ```

`string`  data type is not defined in C. Second argument should be `char* argv[]`.

Please see the answer :[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709323/does-c-have-a-string-type#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20string%20type,one%20additional%20zero%20terminating%20character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709323/does-c-have-a-string-type#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20string%20type,one%20additional%20zero%20terminating%20character).

Comment: `string` is a `typedef` for `char *` in Harvard's CS50 course. See the [tag info for CS50](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cs50/info).

Comment: I still don't understand why they don't just use char * but, what do I know, I'm a beginner.